# DataSource conflict in Spring Batch and Spring Batch admin integration

Tags: spring, datasource, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using Spring Batch Framework in my application, in which I have successfully integrated Spring Batch Admin. When I am trying to Create bean for JdbcTemplate. it is giving me following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: dataSource,phoenixDataSource
```

where 'dataSource' is used by Spring Batch Admin, and 'phoenixDataSource' is created by me. how do I differentiate in both, is there any way to provide @Qualifier to BatchAdmin used dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you rename `phoenixDataSource` to `dataSource` and load your application context first before the spring batch admin beans.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @Ashish, you may use a Qualifier for referencing the datasource that you want to use.

```
@Qualifier("phoenixDataSource")
private Datasource datasource;

@Qualifier("phoenixDataSource")
public class PhoenixDatasource{

}
```